# Java creating logfile java0.log and lock file in /root folder

Tags: java, logging, java.util.logging

I am working on large project.
Java creating very huge logfile java0.log and lock file in /root folder with following contains :

```
<record>
  <date>2015-12-15T00:15:42</date>
  <millis>1450118742727</millis>
  <sequence>22</sequence>
  <logger>javax.xml.bind</logger>
  <level>FINE</level>
  <class>javax.xml.bind.ContextFinder</class>
  <method>lookupJaxbContextUsingOsgiServiceLoader</method>
  <thread>1</thread>
  <message>Unable to find from OSGi: javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext</message>
</record>
<record>
  <date>2015-12-15T00:15:42</date>
  <millis>1450118742727</millis>
  <sequence>23</sequence>
  <logger>javax.xml.bind</logger>
  <level>FINE</level>
  <class>javax.xml.bind.ContextFinder</class>
  <method>find</method>
  <thread>1</thread>
  <message>Searching META-INF/services</message>
</record>
<record>
  <date>2015-12-15T00:15:42</date>
  <millis>1450118742727</millis>
  <sequence>22</sequence>
  <logger>javax.xml.bind</logger>
  <level>FINE</level>
  <class>javax.xml.bind.ContextFinder</class>
  <method>lookupJaxbContextUsingOsgiServiceLoader</method>
  <thread>1</thread>
  <message>Unable to find from OSGi: javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext</message>
</record>
<record>
  <date>2015-12-15T00:15:42</date>
  <millis>1450118742727</millis>
  <sequence>23</sequence>
  <logger>javax.xml.bind</logger>
  <level>FINE</level>
  <class>javax.xml.bind.ContextFinder</class>
  <method>find</method>
  <thread>1</thread>
  <message>Searching META-INF/services</message>
</record>
```

I tried setting log level in different logging.properties
 files but still those logs are coming up.
Any idea how to disable this logging ?

Comment: The first question should be why in the name of all that is good are you running Java as root?

Comment: Its a legacy code :)

Comment: Is the code itself installing this FileHandler?  You can try calling LogManager.reset().

Comment: @jmehrens adding LogManager.reset() solved my problem. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [java.util.logging.LogManager.reset()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/logging/LogManager.html#reset()) to reload the default system configuration.  If the legacy code is programmatically installing the handler then calling 'LogManager.reset()' will remove and close the handler.  Since the existing handler is not defined in the `logging.properties` it will not be recreated.

Alternatively you can use the LogManager to [enumerate](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/logging/LogManager.html#getLoggerNames()) all loggers and try to track down the handler, remove, and close it.